Evaluating functions defined by an indefinite integral
I'm a maths novice. I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out. Suppose I have a function defined by an indefinite integral like this:
$$
F(x) =\int_{}^{}f(x)dx
$$
Now, let's also suppose I cannot or do not know how to solve the integral analytically. So maybe the function f(x) could be $$ f(x) = e^{-x^{2}} $$
What I'm interested in is if and how I can evaluate the function F(x) for a specific value of x without solving the integral analytically, strictly by knowing the function f(x) (for simplicity I set the integration constant C=0). I feel like the answer to this question should be blatantly obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out and when I searched for the answer, I apparently wasnt't able to formulate the question clearly enough to find an answer.
I do understand there is the relation $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx= [F(x)]_{a}^{b}=F(b)-F(a)$$
but this way, if I was interested in the value of F(b), I'd have to ensure that F(a)=0, which is not exactly trivial.
I'm sorry if this is too obvious, as I say, I'm a novice and I'm somehow unable to figure this out and my head is already fried. Thank you for any answers.
EDIT: I do expect to rely on numerical integration. Here my problem is mainly that usually we calculate integrals for some lower and upper bound and I'm interested in knowing if I can calculate a value of the antiderivative at a specific point, not a difference of 2 values.

It'll largely depend on the function chosen, and the points at which you want to evaluate the integral. This is one of the difficulties of dealing with functions with nonelementary antiderivatives. About the best you can hope for in a "one size fits all" solution is something like Taylor series approximation or other such methods. (Though Taylor series requires constraints, like being within the interval of convergence and $f$ being $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.)

Your question is way too broad to have an answer. There are some techniques to calculate some families of integrals without solving them analytically, I recommend you to read a book on integration to discover some of them.

$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt $ would be a better way of having F(x) , for any x, if you have no antiderivative , you have to do numerical integration from a to x or a Taylor series. so there is no easy other way , so let your head not fry.

$F$ is only determined up to a constant, hence the word indefinite. All you can ever hope to evaluate is therefore the difference between $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ for some $y\neq x.$
Some integrals do not evaluate in closed form, although if the applications are important enough people will invent a new name for them and call it closed, such as the natural logarithm which arises from integrating the simple rational function $f(x)=1/x,$ or elliptic functions arising from the integral of an algebraic function involving a square root.
If the integral does not evaluate to any function with a name in a software library, then your best hope is a numerical integration method for the definite integral of $f$ between $y$ and $x.$

Thank you for your answer, it's actually really helpful! :) I wanted to ask how we would plot ln(x) if we knew nothing about it, only that it was the antiderivative of 1/x, but I suppose if we knew ln(1)=0 in advance, then we would simply use the formula I mentioned at the end which would make things a lot easier.
